# Confusion: homogeneous Weierstraß equation for elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am learning about the basics of elliptic curves, using Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry (that can be found [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), chapter 19, "genus one curves"). Here, he establishes that an elliptic curve over a field $k$ (with $\operatorname{char}(k) \not = 2,3$) may be described as a cubic regular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$ defined by an homogeneous equation of the form 
$$\begin{equation}\tag{E} y^2z=x^3+ax^2z+bz^3 \end{equation}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are parameters taken in $k$ (Weiestraß normal form).

Now, in many sources, a Weierstraß equation is rather defined as 
$$\begin{equation} \tag{E'}y^2=x^3+ax+b \end{equation}$$
which is supposedly obtained from $(\operatorname{E})$ by looking at the intersection with the distinguished open affine subset of $\mathbb{P}^2_k$ defined by $z\not = 0$.

This correspondance is even stated in the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/intuition-behind-elliptic-curves-and-k-rational-points?rq=1).

But when taking $z=1$ in $(\operatorname{E})$, the equation we actually obtain is $y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$, right? What happened to the $x^2$ term then?

I could guess two possible explanations for this, and I am confused about which one is correct.

**First explanation**, there is a typo, and the actual Weierstraß normal form would rather be $y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3$. This would be consistent with the fact that in Vakil's note, page 516, he actually states that we make the coefficient of $x^2z$ equal $0$ by translating the variable $x$ with a multiple of $z$.

**Second explanation**, after taking $z=1$ in $(\operatorname{E})$ and getting the equation $y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$, we translate the variable $x\rightarrow x-\frac{a}{3}$ to eliminate the $x^2$ term. Then, when we associate the equations $(\operatorname{E})$ and $(\operatorname{E'})$, it is implicitly meant that the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily the same (namely after translating the variable $x$, we obtain coefficients $a'=-\frac{a^2}{3}$ and $b'=b+\frac{2a^3}{27}$ for $(\operatorname{E'})$).

Is any of these two explanations the correct one?
I thank you very much for your clarification.

Comment: I'm sure your first explanation is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you very much @LordSharktheUnknown for clarifying ! Then, I shall always use the the equation $y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3$ instead when dealing with elliptic curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your explanations are correct. Surely, there is a typo in the notes you are reading, as the standard short Weierstrass model is of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. However, as you note, it is also true that every elliptic curve over a field of characteristic $\neq 2,3$ has a model of the form $y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$ (and one can go back and forth using the change of variables you note). I would suggest you also read a more standard source along with the notes you are reading, such as Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" which contain more details that may be useful and clarifying.

Comment: Thank you very much for you clarification and suggestion. I will do so and check this source.